"something went wrong" when creating Instagram account
I just created a new Instagram account using the website on my PC (not the mobile app).
After I went through the steps, and entered the confirmation code, I got an error:

"Sorry, something went wrong while creating your account. Please try again soon."


If I now try to log in, it says "Your account has been disabled for violating our terms."
Clearly, this is a mistake since I haven't been able to log in to the account yet.
What steps can I take to resolve this? Is there any official Instagram support that will respond? I really do not want to lose the username. Literally just bought the corresponding domain :(

Update: I have contacted support@instagram.com and security@mail.instagram.com with a description of the problem. However, it is widely suggested that a response is highly unlikely.

Last year I had a similar problem with Instagram and Facebook. Apparently this happens when the account doesn't have a verified phone number.
Workaround

Create the account using the mobile app.
Set a phone number.
Complete the verification process.


Thanks, but it is too late for that now. The account has been created and is disabled. This means the username is no longer available, and I cannot simply create a new account with that username. So I am looking for a way to trigger a manual review.
PS: It only asked me for an email, no phone number, so sounds like the same problem you faced.

Try to log in using one of the mobile apps on a phone / tablet that you have not used for Instagram and Facebook. If You don't have another device uninstall these apps, do deep device clean up, restart the device and try again ( install Instagram, etc.,)
